# Error 1004 with open filename, hyperlink to CSV, string length issue? - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to download CSV files but the hyperlinks are too long. With the working length of only ~10 stock symbols this would take way too long. Anything more returns an error 1004 "open of object workbook failed". Is there any way I could maximize accepted string length to cut down on the number of loops?

The link/cell reference is this:
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOGL+GOOG+MSFT+AMZN+HDB+FB&f=nsaa5bb6

The code is:

```
Sub test()

Dim csvlink As String
Dim rows As Long

For rows = 1 To 30
    csvlink = Sheets(1).Cells(rows, 1).Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=csvlink
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
    Workbooks("test file.xlsb").Activate
    Sheets(3).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next rows

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy` should be `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Copy` unless you are **always** using Sheets(3).Range("A1") as the target (which does not appear to be true).

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. I didn't notice this since I haven't gotten past the first sheet, thank you!

Comment: If speed is an issue (and it usually is for stock quotes) then use an MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 object to gather data from http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOGL+GOOG+MSFT+AMZN+HDB+FB&f=nsaa5bb6

Comment: That seems like a good workaround. There will still be 500+ loops and this will eventually be refreshed constantly (for realtime ask/bid sizes) so I am concerned about query limits. My webservice code yesterday was actually exceeding bandwidth but I'll try something different and keep refining. Thank you Jeeped!

Comment: Query strings have a size limit but you should be able to POST the data (much larger limit) into that alternate URL.